# Closing and reverting to original image within a simple jQuery gallery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the simple jQuery gallery from [Papermashup.com](http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-gallery/), and need help extending it's function. I currently have 4 thumbnails and 1 main image. However, I want to be able to revert back to the original image without having an extra thumbnail of the original image. Is there anyway to revert to the original, if and when you click on another thumbnail?

HTML:

```
<div class="main"><img src="main.jpg"></div>

<div class="thumbs">
   <a class="t" href="main-lrg.jpg" rel="1"><img src="main-1.jpg"></a>
   <a class="t" href="main-lrg.jpg" rel="2"><img src="main-1.jpg"></a>
   <a class="t" href="main-lrg.jpg" rel="3"><img src="main-1.jpg"></a>
   <a class="t" href="main-lrg.jpg" rel="4"><img src="main-1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.t').click(function() {
        var image = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.main').hide();
        $('.main').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.main').html('<img src="' + image + '">');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: so if someone clicks on a thumbnail you want the main picture to change, but also revert back to the original.  I'm not understanding.

Comment: Yes. So if I click a thumbnail to view image 2, I also what to be able to close image 2 and see the original image, image 1. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: How do you want to close image 2. I don't think you want to revert back to the original by clicking another thumb. maybe if you click the same thumb or some type of mouseleave.

Comment: My initial idea was to have a close button like you see on those Lightboxs. So when you click and view image 2, a close button would show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the original image `src` attribute when the DOM loads so you have a reference to it. Then, when you want to show the original image again you can just set the main image's `src` attribute back to the original. For example, if you had a button with the id "close" that was supposed to show the original image it would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var original = $('.main img').attr('src');

    $('#close').click(function() {
        $('.main img').attr('src', original);
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.t').click(function() {
        var image = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.main').hide();
        $('.main').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.main').html('<img src="' + image + '">');
        $('#close').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to show the close only when you click one of the thumbnails?

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer so the close button is shown when you click a thumb and hidden when the original is shown. You'll want to add CSS to hide the button initially.